# gsutil copy file from google storage bucket to local machine got error "Python was not found"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I have set environment variable by below code:

```
setx CLOUDSDK_PYTHON "C:\users\xxxxx\miniconda3\python.exe"
```

result from "where.exe python" :

C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

"gcloud info" result is as below, thank you for your help.

```
Google Cloud SDK [319.0.0]

Platform: [Windows, x86_64] uname_result(system='Windows', node='LAPTOP-xxxxx', release='10', version='10.0.18362', machine='AMD64', processor='Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel')
Locale: ('en_AU', 'cp1252')
Python Version: [3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]
Python Location: [C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\python.exe]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  bq: [2.0.62]
  core: [2020.11.13]
  gsutil: [4.55]
System PATH: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\sdk;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.4.0\;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\xxxxx\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin]
Python PATH: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\lib\third_party;C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\python38.zip;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\DLLs;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3\lib;C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda3]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]
Kubectl on PATH: [False]

Installation Properties: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\properties]
User Config Directory: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\configurations\config_default]

Account: [xxxxx]
Project: [xxxxx]

Current Properties:
  [accessibility]
    screen_reader: [False]
  [core]
    account: [xxxxxxxx]
    disable_usage_reporting: [True]
    project: [xxxxx]

Logs Directory: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs]
Last Log File: [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2021.02.04\19.32.09.496751.log]

git: [NOT AVAILABLE]
]sh: [OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the output from the command `gcloud info`. When you installed the Google Cloud SDK, there is an option to disable installing the "bundled Python". I recommend that you reinstall the SDK and include Google's version of Python which is only used by the CLI. Update your question with more details on how you setup the SDK if my suggestion is incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @JohnHanley comment and I noticed  that you are using very old Cloud SDK (current version 326.0.0) so reinstalling should correct this as well

Comment: @JohnHanley,yes after reinstall the latest SDK, it is working. thank you both!

Comment: About a month ago there was a broken release of the SDK. In your case I think you had two problems. Not using the bundled version of Python when installing and the broken build.